# how to call session bean method with a certain role when calling from an MDB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, jaas

My Session bean has several methods defined.
Some can be accessed by ADMIN role only, others can also be accessed by USER role.

```
@Stateless
@DenyAll
public class MyBean {
  ...
  @RolesAllowed({"ADMIN"})
  public void foo() { ... }

  @RolesAllowed({"ADMIN", "USER"})
  public void bar() { ... }
}
```

This session bean is invoked by a message driven bean.

```
@MessageDriven(...)
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
    public onMessage(Message message) {
        MapMessage msg = (MapMessage) message;
        String role = msg.getString("role");
        String action = msg.getString("action");

        if ("ADMIN".equals(role)) {
            if ("foo".equals(action)) {
                // TODO: call as ADMIN role!
                myBean.foo();
            }
            else if ("bar".equals(action)) {
                // TODO: call as ADMIN!
                myBean.bar();
            }
        }
        else if (role.equals("USER")) {
            if ("foo".equals(action)) {
                // TODO: call as USER role!
                myBean.foo();
            }
            else if ("bar".equals(action)) {
                // TODO: call as USER!
                myBean.bar();
            }                
        }
    }

    @EJB
    MyBean myBean;
}
```

Since MDBs do not have credentials associated with them, I cannot propagate the security to the session bean. Right now I am passing the user's role as part of the message. But how do I execute as the role I specified?

Answer (score 1):

You can propagate a security context by declaration of `@RunAs` annotation on the MDB. Unfortunately you once you declare a `@RunAs` role is not possible to change it programatically. Here is an example:

```
@MessageDriven(...)
@DeclareRoles("ADMIN")
@RunAs("ADMIN")
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
}
```

The user that invokes the session bean from the MDB must be mapped to the intended role:

```
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <principal-name>userCallingFromMDB</principal-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
```

If you absolutely need to pass users with multiple roles, you might try to create a group with these users and use `@RunAs("GROUP")` (I didn't try that but seems possible from the docs.)

See also these 2 links:

- [propagating a security identity](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnbyr/index.html)
- [mapping roles to users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnbxv/index.html)